# Prove that $f(x)=(e^x-1)(x^2+3x-2)+x$ has exactly one positive root, exactly one negative root and one root at $x=0$.

Tags: calculus, functions, roots, exponential-function

Prove that the function

$f(x)=(e^x-1)(x^2+3x-2)+x$

has exactly one positive root, exactly one negative root and one root at $x=0$.

My work so far:

$f(0)=0$

Thus, $x=0$ is a root.

For the positive root,

$f(\frac{1}{4})=(e^{\frac{1}{4}}-1)((\frac{1}{4})^2+3(\frac{1}{4})-2)+(\frac{1}{4})
               =(e^{\frac{1}{4}}-1)(\frac{1}{16}+\frac{3}{4}-2)+\frac{1}{4}
               =-\frac{19}{16}e^{\frac{1}{4}}+\frac{23}{16}
               <0$
$f(1)=(e^1-1)((1)^2+3(1)-2)+(1)
     =(e^1-1)(1+3-2)+1=2e^1-1
     >0$

Thus, there is at least one positive root, by the intermediate value theorem. I have also done the same thing for the negative root, as $f(-4)<0$ and $f(-2)>0$.

But how do I show that there is only one positive root and only one negative root?

Comment: Solve $f'(x)=e^x (x^2+5x+1) - 2x -2 = 0$, i.e. $e^x (x^2+5x+1) = 2x +2$. Because $e^x$ doesn't change the sign of $x^2+5x+1$, $y=e^x (x^2+5x+1)$ at most has two intersection points with the line $y=2x +2$. Thus $f(x)=0$ at most has three roots, and you have found them all.

Comment: @Stan How do you know that $y=e^x(x^2+5x+1)$ has at most 2 intersection points with the line $y=2x+2$? And if so, why does it follow that $f(x)=0$ has at most three roots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(To state my solution more rigorously and clearly, I put my comment into an answer.)

First, it is easy to calculate:

$$
f'(x) = e^x (x^2+5x+1) - 2x -2 \\
f''(x) = (x+1)(x+6)e^x-2 \\
f'''(x)=e^x(x^2+9x+13)
$$

Second, we will check how many real roots $f''(x)=0$ has:

> - **Case** $-\infty<x \leq -1$:
>
>   Calculate $f'''(x)=0$, we get the stationary points of $f''(x)$ are at
>
>   $$ x_{1} = \frac{-9 + \sqrt{29}}{2}, ~ x_{2} = \frac{-9 - \sqrt{29}}{2}$$
>
>   Then evaluate: $f''(x_1)\approx -2.55543$, $f''(x_2)\approx -1.99445$. Besides,
>
>   $$ \lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} f''(x) = -2$$
>
>   and $f''(-1)=-2$. Thus,
>
>   $$\max_{-\infty < x \leq -1} f''(x)=f''(x_2)\approx -1.99445 < 0$$
>
>   That is, in this case, there's **no** real root for $f''(x)=0$.
> - **Case** $x>-1$:
>
>   In this case, it is easy to check $f''(x)$ is monotone increasing and is able to go larger than 0. Thus, there's **exactly one** real root for $f''(x)=0, x>-1$.
>
> > **Conclusion**: $f''(x)=0$ has exactly one real root.

Finally, we will utilize [Rolle's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem):

> > (Given proper continuity and differentiability.) If $f'(x)=0$ has exactly $n$ real roots, then $f(x)=0$ ***at most*** has $n+1$ real roots.
>
> Why? If we can find $n+2$ real roots for $f(x)=0$, say
>
> $$x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_{n+2}$$
>
> according to Rolle's theorem, there will exist $c_1 \in (x_1,x_2)$, $c_2 \in (x_2,x_3)$, ..., $c_{n+1} \in (x_{n+1},x_{n+2})$, such that
>
> $$f'(c_1) = f'(c_2) = \cdots = f'(c_{n+1}) = 0$$
>
> It will contradict "$f'(x)=0$ has exactly $n$ real roots".

Now, we can see because $f''(x)=0$ has exactly one real root, $f'(x)=0$ will **at most** have two real roots, and then $f(x)=0$ will **at most** have three real roots. And you have found the three roots for $f(x)=0$, so there're no more roots.

---

**Note**: Be careful of the "at most" statements above. It does **NOT** mean the equation must have such many roots.

Answer (score 0):

I bet, you have to find any two positive numbers `a` and `b`such that `f(a)<0` and `f(b)>0`. Thus, it will prove that there is one positive root that is between `a` and `b`.

Same logic applies for the negative root.

Comment: That proves that there exists a positive root between A and B, which BenJames has already done. However, it does not guarantee that there is exactly one real root.

Comment: Yes, I have already shown there is at least one, I want to show that there is only one.

Comment: Well, then he has to prove that the function is monotonic in the region described above.

Comment: @TarasMurzenkov But the function isn't monotonic is it? It has at least 3 roots.

Comment: Isn't it enough just to prove that the function has to be monotonic within the stated boundaries?

Comment: It would be enough if the function was monotonic but I don't think it is. Can you show me why it is?

Comment: @TarasMurzenkov It would be enough if the function was monotonic but I don't think it is. Can you show me why it is?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the fact that the function is differentiable (and continuous) at all $R$, to find a contradiction:

Suppose that $0 <a <b$ with $a$, $b$, roots of $f(x)$, with $0$, $a$, $b$, consecutive roots, then there exists $c_1\in[0,a]$ and $c_2 \in[a, b]$ such that $f(x)$ reaches maximum or minimum, as the function is twice differentiable we have:

$$f''(x)=e^x(x^2+5x+1)+e^x(2x+5)-2$$
$$f''(x)=e^x(x^2+5x+1)+2xe^x+5e^x-2$$
how $5e^x>2$, $f''(x)$  is always positive for all $x>0$ then $c_1$ and $c_2$ are both minimuns, but this implies that there is no tangent line at $a$ which contradicts the fact that $f(x)$ is differentiable at all $R$.

God bless